# DSolve Varying Base on Implementation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I am trying to understand the behavior of a system of equations that is derived from:

```
 ClearAll[x, y, t, q, d, sol]; ode1 = 
 y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t]; ode2 = 
 x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]; ic = x[0] + y[0] == 1 

 sol[t_, d_, q_, x0_, y0_] = {x[t], y[t]} /. (First@
    Simplify[DSolve[{ode1, ode2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]])
```

Then `sol[t, 0.1, 0.973, 0.185, 1 - 0.185]` gives:

```
{0.0342878 E^(-5.00005 t) (0.1 (4.79594 - 1.73663 E^(1.85411 t)) - 
4.54186 (-1 + E^(1.85411 t)) + 
0.973 (5.77198 - 5.56802 E^(1.85411 t) + 1.85411 E^(5.00005 t)) + 
2.78116 (-0.445 - 0.445 E^(1.85411 t) + 
   2 E^(5.00005 t))), -0.0342878 E^(-5.00005 t) (-0.0461897 (-1 + 
   E^(1.85411 t)) + 
0.1 (2.06376 - 9.27624 E^(1.85411 t) - 1.85411 E^(5.00005 t) + 
   0.973 (-1.37665 - 3.15665 E^(1.85411 t)) + 
   2.31475 (-1 + E^(1.85411 t))) - 
3 (0.973 (2.9561 + 0.0660979 E^(1.85411 t)) - 
   1.54317 (-1 + E^(1.85411 t)) + 
   0.927054 (1.445 + 1.445 E^(1.85411 t) + 2 E^(5.00005 t))))}
```

But if I put into Mathematica:

```
ClearAll[x, y, t]
q = .973;
d = .1;
ode1 = y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t];
ode2 = x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t];
ic = {x[0] == .185, y[0] == 1 - .185};
DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

I get the output:

```
   {{x[t] -> 
   0.110786 E^(-8.146 t) (2.90926 E^(3.14595 t) - 
      3.51923 E^(5.00005 t) + 7.82919*10^-18 E^(6.29189 t) + 
      2.27986 E^(8.146 t) + 2.50534*10^-16 E^(10.0001 t)), 
  y[t] -> 0.204954 E^(-8.146 t) (2.90926 E^(3.14595 t) + 
      0.105679 E^(5.00005 t) + 1.69279*10^-17 E^(6.29189 t) + 
      0.961567 E^(8.146 t) - 8.46397*10^-18 E^(10.0001 t))}}
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Your `solX` and `solY` are just `sol[t,0.1,0.973,0.185,1-0.185]`, there is no need to `DSolve` again and make new variables. How did you find root of `solY` (`sol[[2]]`)? If you simplify `sol[t,0.1,0.973,0.185,1-0.185]` you will see, that the second component is a sum of damped exponents with positive coefficients, it definitely can not be equal to 0.

Comment: That's so strange. DSolve again gave `{{x[t] -> 
   0.110786 E^(-8.146 t) (2.90926 E^(3.14595 t) - 
      3.51923 E^(5.00005 t) + 7.82919*10^-18 E^(6.29189 t) + 
      2.27986 E^(8.146 t) + 2.50534*10^-16 E^(10.0001 t)), 
  y[t] -> 0.204954 E^(-8.146 t) (2.90926 E^(3.14595 t) + 
      0.105679 E^(5.00005 t) + 1.69279*10^-17 E^(6.29189 t) + 
      0.961567 E^(8.146 t) - 8.46397*10^-18 E^(10.0001 t))}}` while the original `sol[t, 0.1, 0.973, 0.185, 1 - 0.185]` gave something different. I'll update my post.

Comment: Also, it looks like there are some points outside the graph around the t= 142 for y. Is that the case, or is it just outside the graph's range, because I am getting values between .3 and 0 when I put values for t between 140 and 160 in the equation

Comment: Try using `ParametricNDSolve`, see help page. It allows one to get numerical solution with additional parameters. I have no artifacts and strange behavior with numerical solutions (`NDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolve`), they a re more stable and appropriate if you working with numerical diff. equations.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment. It is possible to get stable `ParametricPlot` inside `Manipulate` if one do not use `Simplify` on `DSolve`, it seems Mathematica makes wrong assumptions then. I tried `Manipulate` with `DSolve` output "as is" (and increased `PlotPoints -> 1000`): perfect curve, no artifacts etc. But nevertheless numerical solutions might be more robust and speedy if you deal with numerical equations.